# FacebookSDK: Share image on my timeline with text/link

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

Is it possible to do so without share dialog? because so far I didn't found anything that allow's that.

This is only share photo without any text:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:self.imageToShare completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) { }];
```

This is only share text without photo:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               self.titleToShare, @"name",
                               self.textToShare, @"description",
                               self.linkToShare, @"link",
                               @"http://www.somesite.com/logo_i.png", @"picture", nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) { }];
```

What do I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the correct answer after search for sometime, the best way to post with a text that you want is this way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageToShare, 1), @"source",
                               self.textToShare, @"message",
                               (self.linkToShare)?self.linkToShare:@"", @"link", nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) { }];
```

Enjoy!